# Field casing issue in Java Jersey Cient

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client

I am using `com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client` to make HTTP calls.

The contract between my Service and the other Service has all fields in upper case.

This is what my class looks like:

```
class UserRequest { 
     private String NAME;
     private String ADDRESS;
     private String ZIP_CODE;
}
```

When I send the request using the below code:

```
ClientResponse response = client.resource("http://localhost:6000/check/it")
        .entity(userRequest, APPLICATION_JSON)
        .post(ClientResponse.class);
```

The other user receives the JsonRequest in this form:

```
{
 "nAME" : "John",
 "aDDRESS" : "www.here.com",
 "zIP_CODE" : "112233"
}
```

Why the only first character automatically converts into the small case in my JSON?
Is there any property which can save me from this?

Comment: I was making some assumptions in my answer which may be incorrect.  How are you configuring Jersey-client's JSON support?

Comment: I don't know something was wrong with the jersey...I changed my client from jersey to RestTemplate now it's working fine. Closing this now

Comment: Could you post your complete entity class with the getter and setter methods.